# How do I Implement auto-scrolling on recyclerView items when they are clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, instagram

I want to implement an `auto-scrolling` effect like the one `Instagram` uses for the `filter` selection. See a video of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3VsKt5Ktao

So when the user `clicks` on an item, it helps the user to `scroll` one item to the left or right. How can this be archived with a `recyclerView`?

Comment: try this sample code on github... https://github.com/florent37/HollyViewPager

Comment: @WaqarYounis This looks good, I will use that if there is no better option

Comment: ok good.................